# Pay Later option not displaying on front end when Paypal option

Tags: civicontribute, joomla, paypal, paylater

Joomla 3.5.1 - Civicrm 4.7.8

I have created a Contribution page (plus a profile with some custom data in it) and wanted to give option to pay later. However, the Pay Later option is not showing on front end whilst the Paypal option is displayed. However, if I remove the option to use Paypal, then the pay later option appears (though with a permanent x in box which cannot be unselected).

I have attempted to replicate on demo site (which is older version - 4.6) and when I choose pay later option it does not display on front end either. However, I cannot remove option to pay by paypal (sandbox) as that breaks the page. So cannot see if pay later would show without paypal.

So, 2 problems 1) pay later not showing with paypal option available -

2) Permanent x in box of pay later when it can be seen on the front end after removing paypal option.

I think this may be a bug but not certain. Wanted advise first.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a history of issues with pay later an pay pal express - there is a ticket on JIRA that sounds like it might be related to what you are reporting can be seen here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18118

Hope this helps,
Tamar

Comment: Tx for this, yes I had seen it but noticed it was closed - should I report this issue there?

Comment: I have now commented on the bug report - will see.